# jquery mouseenter - cursor ignores css instruction

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery to create a clickable link.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h2uH9/1/)

When enter the target `<span id="login">`, cursor should change to a hand and text be underlined. When leave the `<span>`, should revert back to pointer/no_underline.

However, upon first enter `<span>`, the cursor changes to an I-Beam (text underlined), and reverts to pointer (no underline) upon leaving `<span>`. This is not desired behavior. After the first time, though, when enter/leave `<span>` everything works like it should.

How can I prevent the cursor from initially changing to an I-Beam and not a hand upon first entry?

HTML

```
<span id="login">login</span>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).css({'text-decoration':'underline','cursor':'hand'});
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).css({'text-decoration':'none','cursor':'pointer'});
        }
    );
}); //END document.ready()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [CSS cursors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) of 'pointer' and 'default', not 'hand' and 'pointer' (there is no 'hand').

```
$('#login').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'text-decoration': 'underline',
        'cursor': 'pointer'
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'text-decoration': 'none',
        'cursor': 'default'
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h2uH9/4/)**

Comment: Right you are... I confused css and jquery. Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason to set the cursor property on mouse enter - it should be set on the element all the time, because by definition, it describes what the cursor will look like _when the mouse is over the element_. text-decoration is slightly more understandable, but a `:hover` selector is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need javascript to do this. You should be able to do something like this in CSS:

```
#login {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#login:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The CSS `cursor` property defines the mouse cursor that should be used *when the mouse is over the element* - so it can be set at all times, it doesn't have to be added/removed when the mouse enters or leaves. (Incidentally, the pointer-finger cursor is called "pointer", and the standard arrow is just called 'default')

For the underlining, you can use the `:hover` selector to apply a style only when the mouse is over the element. (The `:hover` selector is not, as is sometimes assumed, only available on links)

Trying to do this with javascript is very inefficient, and will only lead to problems down the road. This is standard styling that the browser already fully supports.

Comment: Agree, JavaScript is wholly unnecessary for this purpose.

Comment: Excellent points, and I'll redo my code to use your solution. +1